# Voiceover troubles in the latest iMovie update (August 2019)

Tags: audio, imovie, recording

5 months ago, I recorded a song on iMovie by rapping into a voiceover while the beat was playing. I did this by importing the beat into iMovie and then chose the voiceover function and rapped into my mic. While the voiceover was recording, the beat was playing, so it was easy to rap to the beat.

Today, I tried the same process, but whenever I start a voiceover it mutes all other audio so I can’t hear the beat!

Does anyone know how I can listen to the beat while recording the voiceover?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!